# Call a method from MainActivity class from a non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I have troubles on calling the method update from `MainActivity` class in a   the `MSG0100` non-activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void update(boolean msg100Preselection){
    if(msg100Preselection){
        mExpandableListViewAdapter.setSelectedChild(-1);
        mExpandableListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

And this is my class where i want to call the update method of `Mainactivity`.

```
public class MSG0100{
   boolean msg100Preselection=false;
 pulic void onUpdate(){
     msg100Preselection=true; 
     // Want to call my update method here
     MainActivity activity= new MainActivity();
     activity.update(msg100Preselection); //<-------- Using mainactiviy object crashes my app.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is impossible as you dont have a pointer to your main activity.

The following statement is invalid.

```
  MainActivity activity= new MainActivity();
```

You are not allowed to use the `new` operator to create an activity. That should be done using an intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could do:

1. Move your update method in another class

OR

2. declare your update method as `static` and use it like this:

   `MainActivity.update(msg100Preselection)`;

Answer (score 0):

Try using a callbackListener :-
In your MSG0100 class

```
    public class MSG0100 {
        boolean msg100Preselection = false;
        private static OnUpdateListener mListener;

        public static setListener(OnUpdateListener mListener) {
            this.mListener = mListener;
        }

        public void onUpdate() {
            msg100Preselection = true;
            if (mListener != null)
                mListener.onUpdate(msg100Preselection);
        }

        public interface OnUpdateListener()

        {
            void onUpdate ( boolean msg100Preselection);
        }
    }
```

In your MainActivity-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, OnUpdateListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MSG0100.setListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(boolean msg100Preselection) {
        if (msg100Preselection) {
            mExpandableListViewAdapter.setSelectedChild(-1);
            mExpandableListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        MSG0100.setListener(null)
    }
}
```

This way you won't have any memory leaks or crashes due to Activity being killed.